# Angular activar click en elemento disabled

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Hola quiero detectar el click sobre un elemento, el problema es que este tiene la propiedad disabled = true por tanto no lo detecta, la idea que tengo es que cuando este disabled posicionar el div padre por encima del elemento hijo para que este detecte el click, como podría colocar un div encima de otro?

aqui tengo un ejemplo en donde tengo un input tipo radio desactivado que esta contenido dentro de un div, el cual hay que posicionar encima para que detecte el click incluso cuando le doy click al recuadro del check

```
<div (click) = "click()">
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" [disabled] = "disableButton">
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5pz5nz

Comment: tengo entendido que no hay forma de activar el evento click en un elemento `disabled`

Comment: @LPZadkiel, efectivamente, es por esta razon que pensaba superponer los divs

Comment: Por qué quieres habilitar el click en un elemento deshabitado?

Comment: Para mostrar un pop up donde se le dice al usuario porque está deshabilitado

Answer (score 0):

No es la mejor solución, pero puedes probar a superponer otro div.

```
<div style=" padding:20px;z-index:1000;position:absolute; top:14px" (click)="click()">

</div>
```